# Verilog signed numbers representation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, data, number-systems

I am confused as to when the '-' sign is used and when 's' is used. This [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328618/declare-signed-numbers-in-verilog) is somewhat helping, although not entirely.

Please correct if I am wrong:

For example, to interpret 8'sd244, we write 244 in binary = 11110100. Now it is signed, so the MSB tells us that it is a negative number. So the remaining bits are in 2's complement form, so the actual number stored is -12.

Now when we declare -16'h3A, this is actually 16'hFFC6 in 2's complement form. So declaring these should be equivalent. **But how does Verilog know that 16'hFFC6 must be interpreted as a 2's complement number?**

In other words, are the below the same?

```
a = 16'hFFC6;
```

and

```
a = -16'h3A;
```

Is it different in SystemVerilog and Verilog?

Comment: It is "interpreted" only in some certain context. If that context is an arithmetic expression involving signed types, then it is interpreted as signed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. then a = 16'hFFC6 can be unsigned or signed representation, but unless we specify it to be signed (how to do that?) it is taken as unsigned by default?

Comment: It depends on the type of `a`.  In Verilog-2001 you can specify the signedness even for registers and wires.

Comment: Small example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/gUXD - here you can see that the same hex value is interpreted as signed or unsigned when it is passed to `$display` function - based on it's type only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-` symbol is an operator, not a value. Values get stored in binary and it's only when the value is used as an operand in a larger expression that it matters whether the value gets treated as signed or unsigned.

The numeric literals `8'sd244` and `8'd244` both represent the same bit pattern `8'b11110100` (or `8'hF4), and that's the pattern that gets stored in an 8-bit variable regardless of whether that variable is signed or unsigned. But if you want to compare that pattern with another signed value, or store the pattern in a larger variable, the the *signedness* becomes important.

(8'sd244 < 10) is true because this gets evaluated as
32'hFFFF_FFF4 < 32'h0000_000A

(8'd244 < 10) is false because this gets evaluated as
32'h0000_00F4 < 32'h0000_000A

SystemVerilog did not change anything in this area with respect to how it deals with Verilog signed arithmetic.

Comment: So if I wanted to convert -75 into an 8bit hex number in verilog, would it be -8'h4B or would it be 8'shCB? (75 in binary 1001011, another 1 for signed : 11001011) or would it be 8'h35 in the 2's complement form? (1001011 is 75 -> 2's complement is hex 35)